# Links inside a CSS scroll area using overflow; don't work [Android - PhoneGap/Cordova]

Tags: android, css, cordova, phonegap-build

I have an App build with Phonegap and packaged by PhoneGap Build

```
<!-- App -->
    <div class="app">

        <!-- Header -->
        <div id="header"> 
            <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" width="250px" /></a>
            <br>
            <h1>menu</h1>
        </div> 

        <!-- Content -->
        <div id="content">

            <a href="basic_index.html"><h2>basic</h2></a>
            <br><br>
            <a href="tools_index.html"><h2>tools</h2></a>
            <br><br>
            <a href="weapons_index.html"><h2>weapons</h2></a>
            <br><br>
            <a href="armour_index.html"><h2>armour</h2></a>
        </div> 

        <!-- Footer -->
        <div id="footer"> 
            Copyright 2015
        </div>

    </div>
```

And the CSS...

```
html, body{
  height:100%;
}

body {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;                 
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;              
-webkit-user-select: none;                  
background-color: #4a3424;
background-image: url(background.jpg);
font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
font-size:12px;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
text-transform:lowercase;
overflow: hidden;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

.app {
padding-top: 35px;
padding-left: 25px;
padding-right: 25px;
padding-bottom: 35px;
text-align: left;
overflow: hidden;
}

#header {

position:absolute;
margin-top: 40px;
margin-left: 25px;
margin-right: 25px;
top:0px; 
left:0px; 
height:135px; 
right:0px; 
overflow:hidden;
}

#content {

position:absolute; 
color: #FFFFFF;
margin-left: 25px;
margin-right: 25px;
top:205px; 
bottom:90px; 
left:0px; 
right:0px; 
overflow: scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

#footer {

position: absolute; 
background-color: #1e1e1e;
text-align: center;
bottom: 0px; 
height: 50px; 
left: 0px; 
right: 0px; 
overflow: hidden;
}

a {
text-decoration:none;
}

h1 {
font-size:40px;
font-weight: 700;
margin:0px;
overflow:visible;
padding:0px;
text-align:left;
color: #846142;
}

h2 {
font-size:24px;
font-weight: 400;
margin:0px;
overflow:visible;
padding:0px;
text-align:left;
color: #333;
}
```

The scrolling works fine, however the links inside 'content' work when i run it in a web browser, but don't work when i run the app (made by PhoneGap Build) on my Android phone - not tested iOS or Win Phone yet.

Any ideas whats causing this, and maybe even a solution?

Thanks

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Think a fiddle wouldn't really help, as it works on web browsers, just not when its packaged as an App.

Comment: then upload a zip and share your code

Comment: It was a android 4.3 issue with Overflow. Works fine on 4.4

Comment: and you think all of your users have 4.4 ^^?

Comment: 4.2 it works too but anything lower doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works on 4.2 (That's good enough for me)